# Reactor Kotlin Generic type return

Tags: generics, kotlin, project-reactor

Does any one knows why generic type is turned into `Nothing!` and cannot be chained with Reactor onErrorReturn?

```
fun test(): Mono<out String> {
        return Mono.just("")
    }
// Compile error
test().onErrorReturn("dummy")
```

> Type mismatched 
>   Required: Nothing!
>   Found: String
>   Projected type Mono restricts use of public final fun onErrorReturn...

However, if I use `map` and `onErrorReturn` at another function, it works

```
// No error
fun useTest(): Mono<String> {
        return test().map { "haha" }
    }
useTest().onErrorReturn("hehe")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Mono<out String>` means basically `Mono<some subtype of String>`. I.e. "`Mono<String>` or `Mono<Nothing>`"; so for

```
test().onErrorReturn(x)
```

to compile, the type of `x` must work whether `test()` returns a `Mono<String>` or `Mono<Nothing>`. If it's a `Mono<String>`, `x` must have type `String`; if it's a `Mono<Nothing>`, it has to be `Nothing` (which is why `"dummy"` doesn't typecheck). So it has to be a subtype of both `String` and `Nothing`; which is `Nothing`.

The compiler doesn't actually consider these as separate cases, but the outcome is the same.

Comment: could you elaborate more on

"every subtype of `String`. which makes it `Nothing`"?

Comment: Thanks, this does explain why it turns into `Nothing`
Because of `Nothing`, does it mean I shall not use Mono with `out` in Kotlin? basically, it loose type information in most of Mono methods.
There is no class in Java being subtype of everything, it will not be a problem of Java.

Comment: The Java equivalent of `Mono<out String>` is `Mono<? extends String>`, I expect it would run into exactly the same problems (e.g. `.onErrorReturn("dummy")` also shouldn't work; if it does, likely the compiler notices `String` is final and simplifies it to `Mono<String>`). If you look here https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html, you can see it's never used as a return type, but it's useful as a parameter type. Same in Kotlin.

Comment: yep, you are right, Java has the same problem. So how do I return a Mono of some type can be its subtypes?

Comment: Well, this _is_ the way you do it. The problem is just that you can't do quite a few things with it, but 1. there are some you can, you give an example `test().map { "haha" }` yourself; 2. you can't really avoid it. I think the best is to convert it to `Mono<String>` (in this example; `test().map { it }` should do it) and then work as usual.